# Get difference between two days (minus method)

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I've got two dates:

`def lastRequestDate = "08-09-2019"` (MM-dd-yyyy)

and

`def today =  new Date().format('MM-dd-yyyy')`

I'm trying to get the difference with groovy [minus](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#minus(java.util.Date)) method:

```
def lastRequestDate = "08-09-2019"
def today =  new Date().format('MM-dd-yyyy')

def difference = today.minus(lastRequestDate)

println "difference: " + difference
```

but instead of days amount (1), I'm getting today's date: `08-10-2019`

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I saw such a method, but I'm trying to use `minus` method to get the date difference.:

```
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
def duration = endDate – startDate
return duration.days
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: you are applying minus method to [String (Charsequence)](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/CharSequence.html#minus(java.lang.Object)). `lastRequestDate` contains string. [Date.format](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)) returns string. to use `Date.minus` you need to have Date object in a variable.

Comment: I've tried: `def lastRequestDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy").parse("08-09-2019")` but it still doesn't work

Comment: *FYI:* `today.minus(lastRequestDate)` can be written as `today - lastRequestDate`. Whether in method form or operator form, **both** operands must be `Date` objects. Yours aren't.

Comment: @Karen in your first example `lastRequestDate` is a String, so you're getting the result of calling `Date.minus()` with a string.
The second example compares two variables of unknown type (probably both are Date variables).
So you can't neccessarily compare both examples.
_Plus_: in the first example you print the string representation of `difference` while in the second one you return the result of the `days` property (`Duration.getDays()` returns an int).
Could you please provide more complete examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def format = 'MM-dd-yyyy'
def simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format)

def lastRequestDate = sdf.parse("08-09-2019")
def today = new Date()

def difference = today.minus(lastRequestDate)

println "difference: " + difference
```

The reasoning behind it is what basically @daggett said:

`def today =  new Date().format('MM-dd-yyyy')` is not returning an actual date, it returns the string representation of today's date in the specified format, so  you actually applied the operation on the string and not on the date

In order to use the `minus` function, you need to apply it on 2 dates, hence the use of `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: @Karen if you have any other questions please feel free to ask. Nevertheless, please accept my answer. Thank you.